# Node for loop in combination with MongoDB query just runs one time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops

I have the following for loop but after I comment out the MongoDB part, it just runs one time/or logs just one time and nothing happens:

```
var listObject = { "324efd03dead881f2e000002": "x", "324efd03dead881f2e000004": "y" };
var count = Object.keys(listObject).length;
var i = 0;
var index;

for (index in listObject) {
    var isLastObject = (i == (count - 1));

    console.log(index);
    console.log(listObject[index]);
    console.log(isLastObject);

    /*
    someCollection.update({ _id: index }, { $set: listObject[index] }, { safe: true }, function(error, result) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(result);
    });
    */

    i++;
}
```

I'm using the latest [MongoDB node driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) and if I remove the comments, I get just logged:

```
324efd03dead881f2e000002
x
false
```

Comment: Well, you'll need to quote the `Object` keys since identifiers can't start with digits. But, after that, [it seems to work as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrULy/).

Comment: Sorry, they were quoted, after some minor script content changes I accidentally removed the quotes. Does it work when you uncomment the commented block?